# I signed a message and got hacked. Can that signature be replayed?

Tags: signature, transfer

I signed a message that contained a nonce: `0x....`. I suspect this message was calculated based on the balance of my account to withdraw the funds that were stolen (fortunately it wasn't a lot).

Can this message be replayed if I were to add more funds to this account?

Answer (score 1):

Since the signed message contained the nonce you can't be replay attacked.

See: "A replay attack is when a signature is used again (“replayed”) to claim authorization for a second action. For our example, it would be a serious security flaw if the recipient of a payment could submit the same signature again to receive a second payment. Just as in Ethereum transactions themselves, messages typically include a nonce to protect against replay attacks. The smart contract checks that no nonce is reused"

from [this](https://programtheblockchain.com/posts/2018/02/17/signing-and-verifying-messages-in-ethereum/)

Comment: In other words, signing a message nonce can be used to authorize an action once. 

So in my case, the `0x...` message I signed that was used to withdraw ETH from my account can't be replayed?

Comment: Not really. A nonce is just a number that is added to the message signature to make sure that message cannot be reused a second time. If that message (i.e. "Me, Adgezaza, sends 1 eth to address 0x...", is reused now, the nonce attached to it will not match your nonce attached to your address and therefore will be rejected. You don't sign a message nonce, a nonce is attached to your message so that message isn't reusable